# Want to calculate cumulative percentage from one table to another table multiple columns

Tags: sql

Input

```
Table 1         Table 2             
Amount      1   2   3   4   5
100     10  10  10  10  10
200     20  20  20  20  20
```

Output

```
    1   2   3   4   5
    10% 20% 30% 40% 50%
    10% 20% 30% 40% 50%
```

I tried to do it in EXCEL and succeed but the data is too large now to do it in excel

NA

\

Comment: I'm lost.  What is table 1 and what is table 2?

Comment: Sorry if it looks confusing actually the table one has a field call amount fianced and table 2 has the return by months I want to get a new table which has the cumulative return percentage.

Comment: How do we relate records in table1 and table2? We need a column to join the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that there is some column in both tables that can be used to join the tables (without this, your question cannot be solved, unless there is only one record in each table).

So assuming the following table structures:

```
table1
    id
    amount

table2
    id
    col1
    col2
    col3
    col4
    col5
```

You can join both tables and do the computation as follows:

```
select 
    t2.col1/t1.amount as col1,
    (t2.col1 + t2.col2)/t1.amount as col2,
    (t2.col1 + t2.col2 + t2.col3)/t1.amount as col3,
    (t2.col1 + t2.col2 + t2.col3 + t2.col4)/t1.amount as col4,
    (t2.col1 + t2.col2 + t2.col3 + t2.col4 + t2.col5)/t1.amount as col5
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

Each column in the result set (apart from `id`) will contain a numeric value between 0 and 1 that represents the cumulative portion of the `amount`. You can then take care of the percent formatting in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but the thing is I have 60 columns not only five is there any more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Only because of the data size I do not want to do it in excel can you please help us a more efficient way of doing it that will be a great help,.